# how to increment question index in a quiz app with button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm trying to increment the question index by clicking on a next button, it seems I'm not getting something.

```
index: number = 1;  
currentQuestion;

next() {
        this.index++;
    }

My Service

    getQuestions(category) {
       return this.http.get(this.url + '&category=' + category + '&type=multiple')
         .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
    }
```

Html:

```
<ion-col size="6">
          <ion-button size="small" color="tertiary" (click)="next()">Next</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
```

Comment: please i'm stuck.

Comment: Have you verified that `next` is being called by putting a console log in it?

Comment: Yes sir frodo2975...

it incremented in the console, but does not move to the next index of the question

I'm using Open Trivia Api, i forgot to mention that

Comment: Ok, cool. Next thing I would do is verify that it's setting the property on the correct `this` since I see your method isn't using `=>` notation. You could add a `debugger;` statement to your `next` method so you could inspect that it's setting it on the right thing.

Comment: If you verify that your controller is good, then the only thing left is your template. You may want to edit your question to show where you're using the `index` var.

Comment: i updated my code,

next() {
  this.index++;
  this.currentQuestion = this.questions['results'][0].question++;
  console.log(this.currentQuestion);
 }

result=== NaN

Comment: If you verify that your controller is good, then the only thing left is your template. You may want to edit your question to show where you're using the index var.


Maybe something of such...

Comment: i am equating the currentQuestion to the index of the question by using [0].question

maybe it will increment it, but it returns NaN in the console

Comment: `this.questions['results'][0].question++` gives the error. You can't increment text. Use something like this: `this.questions['results'][this.index].question`

Comment: Yeah, I see a lot wrong with the code in your comment. First of all, in typescript, you should never access object properties using brackets because you lose all type safety. Secondly, you're doing `question++`, where I'm guessing `question` is an object. You can't increment an object, so that would obviously do something bad. Third, it looks like you're not even using the index property.

Comment: If you setup your typescript types correctly, the compiler should prevent you from making mistakes like this.

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju: Also the queryString in the get method is wrong. Shouldn't be: `return this.http.get(this.url + '?category...')` instead of: `return this.http.get(this.url + '&category.....')`

Comment: @k-vincent sir, what i'm actually doing is that i have different components for different categories, so each component will always get that get request from the service. the this.category passed to the function is like an id, that represent the category of that quiz... Please head to open trivia and you will understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the API you are referring to:

- https://opentdb.com/api_config.php

Then it just returns a random set of questions each time.

There is no concept of `next` in the API.

Just call the same url a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

First in ngOnInit() or IonViewWillEnter(), because I'm using Ionic 4

```
        IonViewWillEnter() {
          // use Ionic storage to store the quizIndex and initialize to 0
          // then get the current index after the api call.
        
          this.storage.get('quizIndex').then(val => {
             this.quizIndex = val;
             console.log(this.quizIndex);
          });
          //now set the data returned from api to a variable called currentQuestion
    
this.storage.get('questions').then(val => {
                this.questions = JSON.parse(val);
                this.totalQuizNum = this.questions.results.length;
                console.log(this.totalQuizNum);
                console.log(this.questions);
    
                if (this.questions !== null && this.totalQuizNum >= this.quizIndex + 1) {
                    this.currentQuestion = this.questions.results[this.quizIndex];
                    console.log(this.currentQuestion);
                    this.answers = this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers;
                    this.correctAnswer = this.currentQuestion.correct_answer;
                    this.answers.push(this.correctAnswer);
                    this.shuffleAnswers(this.answers);
                    console.log(this.answers);
                } else if (this.totalQuizNum < this.quizIndex + 1) {
                    // do something if the total quiz requested from the api = 0 and quizIndex = 0
                }
            });
        
        }
```

This method is repeated due to the next() method:

```
tracks() {
        this.storage.get('questions').then(val => {
            this.questions = JSON.parse(val);
            this.totalQuizNum = this.questions.results.length;

            if (this.questions !== null && this.totalQuizNum >= this.quizIndex + 1) {
                this.currentQuestion = this.questions.results[this.quizIndex];
                console.log(this.currentQuestion);
                this.answers = this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers;
                this.correctAnswer = this.currentQuestion.correct_answer;
                this.answers.push(this.correctAnswer);
                this.shuffleAnswers(this.answers);
                console.log(this.answers);
            } else if (this.totalQuizNum < this.quizIndex + 1) {
                // this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
            }
        });
    }

next() {
        this.tracks();// I don't want to push answers every time I call the next()
        //so that answers won't be pushed twice, causing answer index to return 5 items or answers
        this.quizIndex++;
        console.log(this.quizIndex);
        if (this.quizIndex === this.totalQuizNum) {
            this.showAlert();
            this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/result');
        }
        console.log(this.currentQuestion);
    }

<ion-col size="6">
  <ion-button size="small" (click)="next()" color="tertiary" [disabled]="if 
    something"> Next
  </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```